# I am reciving a bean creation error with my security config class for spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

these are the errors i am getting.. i can't seem to figure out why. i've rewritten the code more than a couple of times and went through the lessons. can someone please take a look? I am working on a basic spring project.

-Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig'

-Error creating bean with name 'usersMapper'

-Mapped Statements collection already contains value for com.udacity.jwdnd.course1.cloudstorage.mapper.UsersMapper.getUser

varun

Answer (score 1):

In the interface **UsersMapper**, you have two methods **getUser()**. Even if the signature are different, it seems to be not supported.

I suggest to rename the **getUser(int id)** by **getUserById(int id)** to solve the issue.

Comment: wow thanks so much vmargerin. that solved it!! i've been trying to figure this out for so long and even re wrote the code a couple of times hoping to catch any mistakes. it worked!